# I can't dump a stacktrace when i use linux trace event triggers

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, stack-trace, ptrace, ftrace

The kernel document 'tracing: trace event triggers' said i can use stacktrace cmd to dump a stacktrace to the trace buffer whenever the trigger event is hit. But all i got is a simple string
"stacktrace".
Here is my configure:

> cd /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/sched_switch
>
> echo 1 > enable
>
> echo 'stacktrace' > trigger
>
> cat trigger
>
> stacktrace:unlimited

When i Looking at the 'trace' output, here is what i saw:

```
    kworker/u2:0-4002  [000] d... 1275475.478000: sched_switch: prev_comm=kworker/u2:0 prev_pid=4002 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=sshd next_pid=3048 next_prio=120
kworker/u2:0-4002  [000] d... 1275475.478000: <stack trace>
        sshd-3048  [000] d... 1275475.478000: sched_switch: prev_comm=sshd prev_pid=3048 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=vim next_pid=4059 next_prio=120
        sshd-3048  [000] d... 1275475.478000: <stack trace>
         vim-4059  [000] d... 1275475.479000: sched_switch: prev_comm=vim prev_pid=4059 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=rcu_sched next_pid=8 next_prio=120
         vim-4059  [000] d... 1275475.479000: <stack trace>
   rcu_sched-8     [000] d... 1275475.479000: sched_switch: prev_comm=rcu_sched prev_pid=8 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=vim next_pid=4059 next_prio=120
   rcu_sched-8     [000] d... 1275475.479000: <stack trace>
         vim-4059  [000] d... 1275475.481000: sched_switch: prev_comm=vim prev_pid=4059 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=rcu_sched next_pid=8 next_prio=120
         vim-4059  [000] d... 1275475.481000: <stack trace>
   rcu_sched-8     [000] d... 1275475.481000: sched_switch: prev_comm=rcu_sched prev_pid=8 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=vim next_pid=4059 next_prio=120
   rcu_sched-8     [000] d... 1275475.481000: <stack trace>
         vim-4059  [000] d... 1275475.482000: sched_switch: prev_comm=vim prev_pid=4059 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=rcu_sched next_pid=8 next_prio=120
         vim-4059  [000] d... 1275475.482000: <stack trace>
   rcu_sched-8     [000] d... 1275475.482000: sched_switch: prev_comm=rcu_sched prev_pid=8 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=vim next_pid=4059 next_prio=120
   rcu_sched-8     [000] d... 1275475.482000: <stack trace>
         vim-4059  [000] d... 1275475.483000: sched_switch: prev_comm=vim prev_pid=4059 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R+ ==> next_comm=rcu_sched next_pid=8 next_prio=120
         vim-4059  [000] d... 1275475.483000: <stack trace>
   rcu_sched-8     [000] d... 1275475.483000: sched_switch: prev_comm=rcu_sched prev_pid=8 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=ksoftirqd/0 next_pid=7 next_prio=120
   rcu_sched-8     [000] d... 1275475.483000: <stack trace>
 ksoftirqd/0-7     [000] d... 1275475.483000: sched_switch: prev_comm=ksoftirqd/0 prev_pid=7 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=rcu_sched next_pid=8 next_prio=120
 ksoftirqd/0-7     [000] d... 1275475.483000: <stack trace>
   rcu_sched-8     [000] d... 1275475.483000: sched_switch: prev_comm=rcu_sched prev_pid=8 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=vim next_pid=4059 next_prio=120
   rcu_sched-8     [000] d... 1275475.483000: <stack trace>
```

How do I make it so that stacktrace dump all the stack traces.

Comment: `echo 1 > enable` are you doing this as sudo? `echo 1 | sudo tee enable`

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: `echo 1 | sudo tee enable`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk whoops, yes, I meant that.

Comment: But i am running as root